# How can i define pattern under servlet filter mapping tag

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, servlet-filters, servlet-listeners

I want to define page url ended with /login under  in  tag....I have written it like,

```
<servlet-filter-mapping>
        <servlet-filter-name>Ip-Filter</servlet-filter-name>
        <url-pattern>web/guest/login</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>c/portal/login</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</servlet-filter-mapping>
```

Can i write it with some pattern like */login or something ??

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) to see what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
<servlet-filter-mapping>
        <servlet-filter-name>Ip-Filter</servlet-filter-name>       
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</servlet-filter-mapping>
```

will match anything ending with **login**, and

```html
 <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
```

will match urls such as *http://server/context/login/index.html* and *http://server/context/login* as well.

some explanations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html)

Comment: @kuhajeyan....with <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern> it is working fine....thank u...

Answer (score 0):

`<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>` will work for all the page url ended with /login...

Comment: rather than answering again by yourself, you should accept the original answer

Comment: @OlafKock ..the answer given is correct but did not perfectly fit in my case thats why i have added answer and also commented that above one is also true ..